# GroovySql: How to update a table with Arraylist variables

Tags: mysql, arraylist, groovy, groovy-sql

I am trying to write an GroovySQL script that will have three different Arraylist variable. A1[1,2,3],A2[4,5,6],A3[7,8,9].

I want to update the table such that three rows of the three columns of the table are updates as
**Data should be (in row wise)**
R1: 1,4,7
R2: 2,5,8
R3: 3,6,9

```
def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/words", "Test",
           "test", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
def nid = 1
def newupdate = "hello world"
sql.executeUpdate("update word set spelling = ? where word_id = ?", [ newupdate, nid])
```

I managed know how to update one row. I will be thankful if anyone can give any hints or ideas.

Comment: Why is this tagged Java? I suggest using 'groovy' and 'groovy-sql'.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is create a 2d array and transpose it, then execute the update query by loop thru it.

Here is the script:

```
//Defined the data that you mentioned
def A1 = [1,2,3]
def A2 = [4,5,6]
def A3 = [7,8,9]

//Chage here your column names that you want to update
//column_0 can be your in your where clause
def columnNames = ['column_0', 'column_1', 'column_2']

//2d array of above data
def matrix = [A1, A2, A3]

//Transpose it to change rows & columns
def transMatrix = (0..<(matrix*.size().max())).collect {
    matrix*.getAt(it)
}
println "Transposed matrix is ==> $transMatrix"



def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/words", "Test", "test", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")

//Loop thru transposed matrix,
//Build the query
//Pass it to executeUpdte
transMatrix.each { rowData ->
    def query = "update word set ${columnNames[1]} = '${rowData[1]}', ${columnNames[2]} = '${rowData[2]}' where ${columnNames[0]} = '${rowData[0]}'"
    println "Generated query is : ${query}"
    sql.executeUpdate(query)
}
```

You may see how the query is build in below:

[image]

Credits to [tim_yates](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6509/tim-yates) for [transpose matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41784018/groovy-transpose-2d-array-different-sizes)