# SoapUI NG Pro - Executing an UPDATE script in SoapUI using Groovy

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, groovy, soapui

I need to be able to execute an update SQL script, but it isn't working

Here is a link to the site that I used for reference:
https://groovyinsoapui.wordpress.com/tag/sql-eachrow-groovy-soapui/

Here is the format of the code that I ended up writing (due to the nature of the work I am doing, I am unable to provide the exact script that I wrote)

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
groovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")

def connectString = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://:;databaseName=?user=&password="

sql = Sql.newInstance(connectString)  // TEST YOUR CONNECT STRING IN A SQL BROWSER

sql.executeUpdate("UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN_1 = 'VALUE_1' WHERE COLUMN_2 = 'VALUE_2'")
```

The response that I am getting is:

```
Script-result: 0
```

I also tried to use:

```
sql.execute("UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN_1 = 'VALUE_1' WHERE COLUMN_2 = 'VALUE_2'")
```

Which returns the following response:

```
Script-result: false
```

Comment: Check if it is helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294903/groovysql-how-to-update-a-table-with-arraylist-variables/42296189#42296189

Answer (score 0):

From what you say it seems that no row has `COLUMN_2 = 'VALUE_2'`, so then number of updated rows is 0.

I would first check that statement on Management Studio just to make sure.

Comment: When I change my query a bit to:
sql.execute """
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN_1 = 'VALUE_2' 
"""
I get:
Script-result: true

Comment: Try `sql.eachRow(" SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN_1 = 'VALUE_2' "){println(it)}` and see what you get.

Comment: Nothing appears to happen.  No message at all. When I execute the following in SQL Server, I get the expected results:
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN_1 = 'VALUE_2'

Comment: So there are 0 row which match your condition. Try with a query for which you know there are result ... if your table is not too big try without the `where`.

Comment: There is for sure a record that matches the criteria I've specified:
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN_1 = 'VALUE_2'

I have verified it directly in SQL Server as well as in Soap using:
def res = sql.firstRow("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN_1 = 'VALUE_2'")

Comment: I don't think I can help you further without seeing the exact statement. Try the prepared statement version of the query, double check types, make sure you are connecting with the right instance / db / schema and so on.

Comment: Here is as close as I can come to the real thing.  Everything is the exact same as my actual script, with mocked values and parameters:
import groovy.sql.Sql

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
groovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")

def connectString = "jdbc:sqlserver://10.110.25.72:60094;databaseName=CUSTOM;user=svcId&password=svcPwd"

sql = Sql.newInstance(connectString)  

sql.execute("UPDATE userInfo SET userStatus = 'active' WHERE userId = '1'")

Comment: maybe userid is an int and you are passing it as a string, remove the quotes.
`userid = 1` instead of `userid = '1'`

Comment: The below updates as expected when I run in SQL Server:
UPDATE userInfo SET userStatus = 'active' WHERE userId = '1'

Comment: Try it without quotes, I'm confident that userId is an int.

Comment: Sorry about the delay. Went home for the night.  I tried both with and without the single quotes. I appreciate you taking the time.  I am stumped.